Target SQL Server Version is incorrect in package XML
I have a new SSIS project that must target SQL Server 2019.
The TargetServerVersion is correctly set to SQL Server 2019 in the project properties. However, when I open a package in XML I see DTS:LastModifiedProductVersion="16.0.5035.3", which corresponds to SQL Server 2022.
Works fine in VS but when we attempt to run it on the server, a script task fails.
As suggested by ChatGPT, I changed DTS:LastModifiedProductVersion to 16.0.3937.0 (which corresponds to SQL Server 2019) in the XML.  Now the package will not open in design view in VS, nor will it run.
I renamed the package, as suggested by ChatGPT, and finally got it to open. Looking in the XML I see that it had reverted back to the 2022 setting.
